# group by month returns only April for two tables

Tags: mysql

Currently I am honestly at loss what I am doing wrong. It is a rather simple query I think.

Tables:

```
  operations:
   id   processedon  clientid
   1    2018-01-01    9
   2    2018-03-16    9
   3    2018-04-21    9
   4    2018-04-20    9
   5    2018-05-09    9


  items:
   id   operation_id  quantity   unitprice
   1      1             10         2
   2      1             5          3
   3      2             20         4
   4      3             10         2
   5      4             8          4
   6      4             10         4
   7      5             2          2
```

The expected result of the operation/query is:

```
 month  total_value
  1      35
  3      80
  4      92
  5      4
```

That is quantity * unitprice based. For some reason, it only returns month=4

```
SELECT 
    month(`operations`.`processedon`) AS `month`, 
    SUM((`items`.`quantity` * `items`.`unitprice`)) AS `total_value` 
FROM `items` 
INNER JOIN `operations` ON (`items`.`operation_id` = `operations`.`id`) 
GROUP BY 'month' 
ORDER BY 'month'
```

Comment: you are grouping by an inexistent column `'month'` actually a string, change the quotes by backticks.

Comment: same in order by

Comment: ```transaction_id``` doesn't seem to be in the table. At least not in your question.

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be using date_format() instead, formatted for year/month? Unless you want multi year results by month (IOW, combining months for all years).

Comment: @SloanThrasher can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: @JorgeCampos thanks! That helped tho oddly enough, it skipped march and i get April and May. Lemme look at it again.

Comment: The comment by @JorgeCampos should make a big difference, and not "oddly enough". Single quotes enclose a string literal. Backticks enclose a column or table name. As written, your GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses will attempt to use the literal value 'month' for each row, while `month` will use the value from the expression, which should vary from row to row, with some being equal.

Comment: To elaborate as requested: If you use MONTH(`operations`.`processedon`) it will return the same value for '2018-04-20' as it does for '2017-04-20', and that would group all values for the same month regardless of year. If you use DATE_FORMAT(`operations`.`processedon`,'%Y-%m') instead, it would group only the data from the same year and month together. Take a look at: [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 1):

The following query will give you the required answer

```
SELECT 
month(`operations`.`processedon`) AS `month`, 
SUM((`items`.`quantity` * `items`.`unitprice`)) AS `total_value`
```

FROM `items` 
INNER JOIN `operations` ON (`items`.`operation_id` = `operations`.`id`) 
GROUP BY month(`operations`.`processedon`)
ORDER BY month(`operations`.`processedon`)

You need to specify month correctly since it is not an existing column.
You'll get the following result
month total_value

```
1 35
```

`3 80`

`4 92`

`5 4`

Answer (score 0):

According to the info provided the join should be

```
INNER JOIN operations ON items.operation_id = operations.id
```

Eg

```
SELECT 
    month(`operations`.`processedon`) AS `month`, 
    SUM((`items`.`quantity` * `items`.`unitprice`)) AS `total_value` 
FROM `items` 
INNER JOIN `operations` ON `items`.`operation_id` = `operations`.`id`
GROUP BY month(`operations`.`processedon`)
ORDER BY `month`
```

There is no efficiency gain by using a column alias in the group by clause, I prefer to avoid using them except perhaps in the order by clause.

Comment: Well, it depends how fast you type. I'm slow, so the efficiency gain is more noticeable

Comment: @Strawberry less typing = good, so I copy/paste... although that wasn't really the purpose of my comment. Some believe there is actually less processing if a column alias is used which isn't true in my experience.

Comment: A little off-topic, but using the alias of an expression vs the expression should make no difference since either way be becomes a placeholder for the value of the expression. But, if you want to reduce typing, alias each table with a single letter so that `items`.`operation_id` becomes a.`operation_id`.